# Str_replace with associated array doesn't do what I would presume that it would do

Tags: php, str-replace

I am currently building a simple function, where I have a string ($string), and an associated array ($map), in which I have every character mapped to the character I want it to be swapped for in the original string.

Here is my code, and I would love if someon could explain to me, what I'm doing wrong here.

```
<?php
$string = "DN RTQK YKOTFR,"

$QWERTY = 'Q,W,E,R,T,Y,U,I,O,P,A,S,D,F,G,H,J,K,L,Z,X,C,V,B,N,M';
$ABC = 'A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z';
$map = array_combine(explode(',', $QWERTY), explode(',', $ABC));
echo str_replace(array_keys($map), array_values($map), $string);
?>
```

Output:

```
Infinite string:
```

However, this code outputs some completely random and infinite string, and even shows some strange behaviour.

- In the original map, every single letter is directly associated with exactly 1 letter, but it outputs the same letter, for 2 different letters.
- If I choose just the first 2 letters in the string, the same thing happens, (outputs ZY, while truly, those 2 letters stand for MY)

Please explain to me what's wrong with this code.
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Please include a [mcve], the expected output and the actual output. Also, what makes you sure that `str_replace()` is the culprit as per your title? As a new user here, please also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: The core of the issue really is `str_replace`, it is explained in the linked duplicate. I'd suggest looking into [`strtr`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr) instead. It can perform what you wish.

Comment: Yep, thank you. :)